# Memory leakage after process terminates

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory-leaks, axis2c

I am returning to C++ after spending a few years in Java, so I have forgotten basics of memory management.

I have to use AXIS2/C for writing a web service client. I read on a lot of forums that AXIS2/C has problems of memory leakage. But, I would be coding short lived client processes, that would die after a couple of transactions. Is memory leakage a problem for such processes?

Can I bank on the Linux kernel to take care of any memory leakages that the C++ code left behind? Don't see any good document about how to free the memory in the AXIS2/C client.

*Jens Gustedt, 
This question is different from the one you pointed out, because it specifically asks about Apache AXIS2/C, seeks information about how to free memory in AXIS2/C.*

Comment: Additional info: I am using version 1.6.0

Comment: Assuming you are not sharing memory with other processes, then memory is cleaned up when your process exits, yes. [And if you are sharing with other processes, the memory is cleaned up when all processes using that memory are closed]. Buggy drivers, however, can cause memory leaks in the kernel which is not cleaned up.

Comment: If it's a process that is started and killed, there is no memory leakage to be taken care of. All memory allocated by normal methods is freed after the process finishes.